# Using MySQL to get average on a specific field

Tags: mysql, date, average

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

```
post_id,user_id,user_post,post_date
```

Basically what I am looking for is the average of users using a specific keyword in their post for each separate day and average of posts containing that specific keyword for each day. Any suggestion how to write such a query ? (It is worth to mention that: the user_post field contains the keywords I am looking for)

By "the average of users using a specific key word" I mean: The fraction of users, say 10/100, using "WORD" at day 1, day 2, ...

I have to mention that the post_date field is varchar and it looks like the following:

```
"Thu Nov 07 15:05:22 EST 2013"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a `datetime` or `timestamp` field for `post_date`.

Comment: Which column contains "specific" Key word?

Comment: @MikeBrant Unfortunately it is too late for that, because I have already collected the data.

Comment: @dognose the user_post field contains the keywords I am looking for.

Comment: @nimafl You could convert the data.  That is beside the point though. Can you show what attempts you have made?

Comment: @nimafl: Sidenode: its never to late to convert data. What do you mean by "average per single day"? Do you need exact count per day, or Average over last 30 days?

Comment: oh, and: Please show your attempts :)

Comment: @MikeBrant I am eager to do so if I have to since the data is really huge and it is time consuming. Unfortunately, I have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: @dognose Let me edit my post :)